# Using preg_replace to clean widget output HTML

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace

I am working on a wordpress site that uses a plugin / sidebar widget. The issue I am experiencing is that the widget generates HTML that is not valid, an example of this is below...

```
<p>
<div>I am item 1</div>
<div>I am item 2</div>
<div>I am item 3</div>
<div>I am item 4</div>
<p></p>
```

From my understanding there are two things wrong with this code, the first being that it uses divs (block level element) inside of a Paragraph. The second being that there is an extra P tag that is not closed at the end.

I have spoken to the widget developers and, even though it is an expensive and paid plugin, are not in any rush to fix the issue.

I am going to attempt to use preg_replace to clean up the code, I was wondering if anyone had any examples or tutorials to doing this and targetting just the code within the widget container?

Comment: A quick tip: There is this site where you can endlessly experiment: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 3):

Firstly when i see your datas (list of items), I think    `<ul> <li>` would be even better :

```
<ul>
<li>I am item 1</li>
<li>I am item 2</li>
<li>I am item 3</li>
<li>I am item 4</li>
</ul>
```

For your preg_replace its even even better if you simply use a str_replace (less exepensive)

```
str_replace(array("<div>","</div>","<p>","</p>"), array("<li>","</li>","<ul>","</ul>"),$yourHtml)
```

Then you delete the empty `<p></p>` (now `<ul></ul>`) by `str_replace("<ul></ul>", "",$yourHtml)`

But the even even even better solution would be to edit the plugin yourself and define a different output !

---

After though, an other "better" solution would be to get all items in an array with [preg_match_all](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-match-all.php).

Exemple :

```
$html="<p>
<div>my item 1</div>
<div>my item 2</div>
<div>my item 3</div>
<p></p>";

preg_match_all("#<div>(.*)</div>#",$html,$matchs);

var_dump($matchs[1]);
//var_dump output : array(3) { [0]=> string(9) "my item 1" [1]=> string(9) "my item 2" [2]=> string(9) "my item 3" }
```

If you dont have `<div>` in `<div>` (i mean : `<div> my <div>item 1</div></div>`) this code would work fine.

In this way you got all your datas in an array and they are more easy to manipulate.
I dont know your php degree, but just execute a foreach loop

```
   foreach($matchs[1] as $v){
      //$v is one item
   }
```

Comment: The problem I have got is that the plugin just sends options over to an API which generates the HTML code and pipes it back to the plugin.  Meaning I have no control over the HTML code it generates.  I am going to try and implement your solution and see how it goes, thanks for your input so far

Comment: If the API doesnt change his output every months this "solution" will be fine but it's not an heavy solution. If you want more look at my answer : I edited and added an other solution.